# 'this' is undefined in a function

Tags: javascript, this

I'm calling `makeALine` function inside of `lines` function.
And I a trying to save line in `makeALine` function, using `this` keyword.

But it says `this` is `undefined`.
I have no idea why it is `undefined`.
Anyone help?

```
function makeALine(setOfDots) {
    let line = {
        model: new makerjs.paths.Line(setOfDots)
    }

    console.log(this) //undefined
    this.paths = line;
}

function lines(obj) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        console.log('value', value)
        let lineType = key.includes(LINE) ? makeALine(value) : null;

        lineTypes.push(lineType)
    }
    console.log(lineTypes)
}
```

Comment: `makeALine(value)` calls it with no calling context, so `this` is undefined (or the global object). Did you mean for `makeALine` to return an object, or call it with `new`?

Comment: In the code you posted, it seems what you want is simply to `return line` from `makeALine(setOfDots) ` so its value will get assigned to `lineType` when calling the function.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ohhh, yes right. I totally forgot ```new```  thanks!!